# Sockets make no sense?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I'm using the 'ws' library for Node.js.

I can write code that sends data from my server to my client, posting a date and time update, and closes the socket when I click a button;

```js
var wss = new WebSocketServer({server: server});
console.log("WebSocket server created");

wss.on('connection', function(socket) {
        // SEND DATE AND TIME EVERY SECOND
 var interval = setInterval(function() {
  socket.send(JSON.stringify(new Date()), function() {});
 }, 1000);

 console.log("WebSocket connection opened");

 socket.on('close', function() {
  console.log("WebSocket connection closed");
  clearInterval(interval);
 });
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      var host = location.origin.replace(/^http/, 'ws')
      var ws = new WebSocket(host);
      ws.onmessage = function (event) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = JSON.parse(event.data);
        document.querySelector('#pings').appendChild(li);
      };

      function pressed() {
        // CLOSE STREAM
        ws.close();
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Pings</h1>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <input type="button"  value="Call server" onClick="pressed()">
    <ul id='pings'></ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

But for some reason I just cannot figure out a way to send data back home to the server, and call the console to print "pressed!" or whatever. This is kind of limiting because instead of being bi-directional, it seems like the socket is a one-way stream.

Like so;

```js
    var wss = new WebSocketServer({server: server});
    console.log("WebSocket server created");

    wss.on('connection', function(socket) {
            // SEND DATE AND TIME EVERY SECOND
     var interval = setInterval(function() {
      socket.send(JSON.stringify(new Date()), function() {});
     }, 1000);

     console.log("WebSocket connection opened");

        // LOOK FOR 'pressed' BEING SENT
       socket.on('pressed', function() {
      console.log("Pressed!");
      socket.close();
     });
      
     socket.on('close', function() {
      console.log("WebSocket connection closed");
      clearInterval(interval);
     });
    });
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      var host = location.origin.replace(/^http/, 'ws')
      var ws = new WebSocket(host);
      ws.onmessage = function (event) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = JSON.parse(event.data);
        document.querySelector('#pings').appendChild(li);
      };

      // SEND 'pressed' TO SERVER
      function pressed() {
        ws.send('pressed');
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <h1>Pings</h1>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <input type="button"  value="Call server" onClick="pressed()">
    <ul id='pings'></ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

What am I missing, just started learning about sockets, feels like I'm trying to dig through a brick wall with a cotton spoon.

Comment: Really, someone decides to downvote a misconception about data interaction in sockets? Legit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client doesn't get to cause arbitrary events to fire on the socket.  It is always a `message` event.  Using the same client, try this server code in your `connection` handler:

```
    socket.on('message', function(data) {
        // data === "pressed", since that's what the client sent
        console.log("Pressed!");
        socket.close();
    });
```

Comment: Works. I feel so stupid right now. I totally understand how socketing works because of this. Thank you, will mark as answered once the 5-min timer is finished.